# Pig - Get Top n and group rest in 'other'

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

I have data that I have grouped and aggregated, looks like this-

```
Date Country Browser Count
---- ------- ------- -----
2015-07-11,US,Chrome,13
2015-07-11,US,Opera Mini,1
2015-07-11,US,Firefox,2
2015-07-11,US,IE,1
2015-07-11,US,Safari,1
...
2015-07-11,UK,Chrome Mobile,1026
2015-07-11,UK,IE,455
2015-07-11,UK,Mobile Safari,4782
2015-07-11,UK,Mobile Firefox,40
...
2015-07-11,DE,Android browser,1316
2015-07-11,DE,Opera Mini,3
2015-07-11,DE,PS4 Web browser,11
```

I want to get the top n browsers (by count) per country, and want to aggregate the rest under 'Other'. I looked into Pig's built-in TOP function, but how would I do the grouping in other. The result I want, for example (n = 2) ->

```
2015-07-11,US,Chrome,13
2015-07-11,US,Firefox,2
2015-07-11,US,Other,3
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Pig is not SQL, so I'm removing that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. This requirement is nice..

I am simply using your input in LOAD statement of Pig script .

Input :

```
2015-07-11,US,Chrome,13
2015-07-11,US,Opera Mini,1
2015-07-11,US,Firefox,2
2015-07-11,US,IE,1
2015-07-11,US,Safari,1
2015-07-11,UK,Chrome Mobile,1026
2015-07-11,UK,IE,455
2015-07-11,UK,Mobile Safari,4782
2015-07-11,UK,Mobile Firefox,40
2015-07-11,DE,Android browser,1316
2015-07-11,DE,Opera Mini,3
2015-07-11,DE,PS4 Web browser,11
2015-07-11,US,Chrome,13
2015-07-11,US,Firefox,2
2015-07-11,US,Other,3
```

Below is the  coding for this.

You can pass a value for  n paramater to pig script, currently I set value 2 for n in the LIMIT statement itself.(i.e n=2).

Actually i hardcoded n=2 in this below code.

```
records     = LOAD '/user/cloudera/inputfiles/entries.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (dt:chararray,country:chararray,browser:chararray,count:int);

records_each    = FOREACH(GROUP records BY (dt,country,browser)) GENERATE flatten(group) AS (dt,country,browser), MAX(records.count) as counts;

records_grp_order = ORDER records_each BY dt ASC , country  ASC , counts DESC;

records_grp     = GROUP records_grp_order BY (dt, country);

rec_each    = FOREACH records_grp {

               top_2_recs = LIMIT records_grp_order  2;
               generate  MAX(top_2_recs.dt) AS temp_dt, MAX(top_2_recs.country) AS temp_country, flatten(top_2_recs.browser) AS temp_browser;

            };
rec_join    =  JOIN records_each BY (dt,country,browser)  left outer , rec_each BY (temp_dt,temp_country,temp_browser);

rec_join_each   = FOREACH rec_join generate dt,country, (temp_browser is not null ? browser : 'OTHERS') AS browser, counts AS counts;

rec_final_grp   = GROUP rec_join_each BY (dt,country,browser);

final_output    = FOREACH rec_final_grp generate flatten(group) AS (dt,country,browser), SUM(rec_join_each.counts) AS total_counts;

sorted_output   = ORDER final_output BY  dt ASC , country  ASC, total_counts DESC;

dump sorted_output;
```

output

```
(2015-07-11,DE,Android browser,1316)
(2015-07-11,DE,PS4 Web browser,11)
(2015-07-11,DE,OTHERS,3)
(2015-07-11,UK,Mobile Safari,4782)
(2015-07-11,UK,Chrome Mobile,1026)
(2015-07-11,UK,OTHERS,495)
(2015-07-11,US,Chrome,13)
(2015-07-11,US,OTHERS,3)
(2015-07-11,US,Firefox,2)
```